# Can SQL Server full-text search tokenize words within words?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

Suppose I have the following schema and data in SQL Server 2012:

```
create table Exclamations
(
    ID int not null primary key identity(1,1),
    Exclamation nvarchar(150) not null
);

insert into Exclamations(Exclamation) values
    ('Ohmygosh!'),
    ('Ohmygoodness!'),
    ('It''sabird!'),
    ('It''saplane!'),
    ('Whattheheck!'),
    ('Lookoutbelow!'),
    ('Whatintheworld?'),
    ('Isheforreal?'),
    ('Takeahike!');

create fulltext index on Exclamations(Exclamation) key index ID;
```

And suppose I want to do full-text queries against my exclamations, but **I want to be able to query for words within words using a high speed index**. Is that possible? Perhaps with a custom dictionary, or custom word-breaking/boundary behavior?

For example, I want to be able to query for the word "out" and have it quickly locate row #6 ('Lookoutbelow!') without having to scan through all the rows using a LIKE-ish operator. This also implies some false positives, for example, suppose I want to query for the word "he" and find row #8 ('Isheforreal?'); the query would also return row #5 ('Whattheheck!') since it contains the same "he" substring. That's OK.

Note that I do not need the tokenizer to index every possible combination of characters. I don't mind if nonsense words like 'sapl' within row #4 are not indexed. I only need it to tokenize the words it already recognizes (and possibly some additional words that I would add, but that is only a nice-to-have.)

It is important to specify that for the purposes of this question I **cannot** pre-parse the exclamations to insert obvious tokenizing boundaries such as spaces, hyphens, or periods, before inserting into SQL Server. I want to know if SQL Server can somehow do that itself.

**EDIT**: After some more reading, it appears that what I want is generally called [N-gram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) tokenizing. But I want it limited to tokens that are already present as, or variants from, words in the dictionary.

Comment: [This article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33419.sql-server-implementation-of-n-gram-search-index.aspx#Indexer)  seems to have a good road map for implementing a DIY version, but there aren't any out of the box features for it as far as I know.

Comment: @JohnM Yeah I saw that article, but to do that much string processing in T-SQL functions seems scary to me. I am evaluating SQL Server FTS vs. Elasticsearch for this use case and I am thinking you are right that there is no built-in feature like this in SQL Server. So I think ES will be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no such feature in SQL Server.

Comment: FYI: A little while after this, I came across a feature called **n-gram tokenization/indexing**, which was well supported in ElasticSearch and met our use case.